# Use panel url for Solr result

Tags: search, panels

I am using Apache Solr on my website and the search form block is configured to use Apache Solr. I also use the [Apache Solr panels module](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr_panels) to panelize my page.

I create a panel on search/my-search/!query, when I use it manually all works fine but when I search via the form search block, I am redirected on the default Apache Solr result page (search/site/!query).

How can I change this behavior ?

EDIT :
Okay, I found the solution by searching a little bit more !

I just disabled the default search block form and put the "Search form (Apache Solr Panels)" in the section I wanted. I only have to restyling my input.

I will put it in a separate answer tomorrow (because of my reputation, I can't answer in the next 8hrs after posting my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for delay, I post here my answer separately from the question :

Okay, I found the solution by searching a little bit more !

I just disabled the default search block form and put the "Search form (Apache Solr Panels)" in the section I wanted. I only have to restyling my input.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == "search_block_form") {
    $form['#submit'] = array('custom_search_redirect');
  }
}

function custom_search_redirect($form, &$form_state) {
  $search_data = $form_state['values']['search_block_form'];
  $form_state['redirect'] = "search/my-search".$search_data;
}
```